# Multi-form Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, transfer

I have 3 Forms that I want to be active at once. 
The first Form is the main window that is used to launch the other two. The problem I'm facing is with data transfer. It works when I use `.ShowDialog();` to launch and transfer data. 
But I don't want the form to lock access to just that window. when I use form `.Show();` It will transfer the data as default "0". Is there anyway around this? 
Is there a better way to achieve the same results, such as a utility window?
 What my end goal is to have separate active windows that will store there variables in the first form.

```
public partial class CH_Info : Form
{
    private Ch_Creation MyChcreation;

    public CH_Info()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyChcreation = new Ch_Creation();
    }
    private void UpdateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this grabs the text from the CH_Creation's STR,DEX,CON,INT,WIS,CHA Total Label
        StrResLbl.Text = MyChcreation.StrTotalLbl.Text;
        DexResLbl.Text = MyChcreation.DexTotalLbl.Text;
        ConResLbl.Text = MyChcreation.ConTotalLbl.Text;
        WisResLbl.Text = MyChcreation.WisTotalLbl.Text;
        IntResLbl.Text = MyChcreation.IntTotalLbl.Text;
        ChaResLbl.Text = MyChcreation.ChaTotalLbl.Text;
    }
```

[This is using  CH_Info MyChInfo = new CH_Info(); MyChInfo.Visible = true;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VXVh.png)  and [this is using .ShowDialog();](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtOkc.png) (The only way It works is if the Dialog box is closed)

The goal is to have the two other forms act as utility windows that I can exit out of and re-open while keeping there data until the program closes. 
Right now I only have `form3` returning data to `Form2`. But I think if I find away to store the variables in the first Form I'll be able to achieve what I want. Which is to return the data back to the other Form when I re-open them. But to clarify, my current problem is keeping all 3 forms active without using `.ShowDialog();` And like I said before, I can transfer data fine aslong as I do not use `.Show();`

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You need to understand what an instance of a class is. And how more than one instance could exist and why the data of one instance is not the same data of another instance. Writing _MyChcreation = new Ch_Creation();_ creates a new instance of the Ch_Creation class. It is not the same instance of the form already displayed

Comment: Is there another way to create the same instance?

Comment: There is only one form of type CH_Creation open at all times in your app?

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one form of type Ch_Creation opened at all times then it is simple a matter of searching the Application.OpenForms collection for your open form of type Ch_Creation and use the instance stored for you by the Winforms engine in that collection

```
public CH_Info()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyChcreation = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Ch_Creation>().FirstOrDefault();
}
private void UpdateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(MyChcreation != null)
    {
        StrResLbl.Text = MyChcreation.StrTotalLbl.Text;
        DexResLbl.Text = MyChcreation.DexTotalLbl.Text;
        ConResLbl.Text = MyChcreation.ConTotalLbl.Text;
        WisResLbl.Text = MyChcreation.WisTotalLbl.Text;
        IntResLbl.Text = MyChcreation.IntTotalLbl.Text;
        ChaResLbl.Text = MyChcreation.ChaTotalLbl.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        StrResLbl.Text = "";
        DexResLbl.Text = "";
        ConResLbl.Text = "";
        WisResLbl.Text = "";
        IntResLbl.Text = "";
        ChaResLbl.Text = "";
    }
}
```

As a measure of precaution always check is a reference variable (like MyChcreation) is null before trying to use its members...

Comment: This seemed to answer my problem. the only thing I'm running into is thatCh_Creation Has to be open before the CH Iinfo. otherwise it wont grab the data.